# How do i use htaccess rules to rewrite to a certain file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have to create a page handler, which should read the URL, and do specific operations based on querystring.

I'd need to use .htaccess to do some URL rewriting thing to point everything at a certain file which does the processing, in such a fashion:

`https://example.com/folder/page1/`

`https://example.com/folder/page2/`

And the processing file is `https://example.com/folder/index.php`

Is there any way to do that (possibly by removing the index.php part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out and see if this helps you achieve what you are looking for.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above code is taken for reference from WordPress and it should work when the "RewriteBase /folder/" folder name is updated with your folder and .htaccess file has to be placed in the root/folder directory where your index.php file is located.